# Android Automotive Navigation in Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-automotive

I have configured emulator with Polestar 2 OS, but still the navigation part is missing. How do I launch the Navigation from my custom app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard maps intents - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents.

Currently the Polestar 2 Or Generic Automotive emulator system image doesn't include maps, so it will be harder to test/validate without hardware.